# Is it possible to stop all the jQuery function before page is reloaded?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

jQuery has sent the aJax function when the page is loaded.

I wonder if these functions can be stop or interrupt before the page is reloaded?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery might be of some help

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on this but you might be able to do this

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation
});
```